# How to fix device is not compatible with the current version of the app issue on Nexus 7 Android OS version 5.1.1 play store

Tags: android

How to fix device is not compatible with the current version of the app issue on Nexus 7 Android OS version 5.1.1 play store.

How to fix device is not compatible with the current version of the app issue on Nexus 7 Android OS version 5.1.1 play store.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

   FEATURE TAG STARTS HERE
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
 APPLICATION TAG STARTS HERE
    <application
        android:name=".CommonClasses.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


//  SERVICES STARTS HERE
        <service
            android:name=".Firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:requ`enter code here`ired="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <meta-data
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is random.There is one way of solving it try going into your phones settings -> applications -> Google play store -> firstly clear cache and then clear data -> Restart play store.This should solve the problem.